# Regex to replace values inside the first curly braces after a specific keyword

Tags: regex

I have an input string and I would like to replace the values inside the first curly braces (including the curly braces) after a specific keyword.

For example in this example I would like to replace the values inside the curly braces which comes after `Honda`.

```
[{brand:”Toyota”, model:”Corolla”}, 
{brand:”BMW”, model:”X3”}, 
{brand:”Honda”, model:”{year:2022, name:Accord}”}]
```

So the end result will be something like:

```
[{brand:”Toyota”, model:”Corolla”}, 
{brand:”BMW”, model:”X3”}, 
{brand:”Honda”, model:”Civic”}]
```

It looks like when using Java I can use replaceAll method to utilize a regex expression but I couldn't figure what should be the regex expression for this use case.

I tried to create a regex like this one below but result was wrong

```
String output = input.replaceAll("Honda.*(?<=\\{).*?(?=\\})","Civic");
```

```
[{brand:”Toyota”, model:”Corolla”},
{brand:”BMW”, model:”X3”},
{brand:”Civic}”}]
```

Comment: The input looks like JSON5. Have you considered using a library to properly parse it? That could be more robust, more performant and more maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look-behinds are problematic because (in Java) they must be fixed-length.
An alternative is to capture the prefix (the brand) and then repeat that as `$1` in the replacement string.

This regex will capture the brand. Notice the surrounding parentheses.

```
(\{brand:"Honda", model:")
```

And this will match the model (excluding the trailing quote):

```
[^"]*
```

Concatenate the two parts. Put them in a string literal, escaping every `\` and `"`:

```
"(\\{brand:\"Honda\", model:\")[^\"]*"
```

Optionally, add `\\s*` to make it robust against arbitrary whitespace:

```
"(\\{\\s*brand\\s*:\\s*\"Honda\"\\s*,\\s*model\\s*:\\s*\")[^\"]*"
```

Make sure the replacement string starts with `$1`:

```
"$1Civic"
```

Working example:

```
class Main
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String input = "[{brand:\"Honda\", model:\"{year:2022, name:Accord}\"}]";
      System.out.println(input);
      String output = input.replaceAll(
         "(\\{\\s*brand\\s*:\\s*\"Honda\"\\s*,\\s*model\\s*:\\s*\")[^\"]*",
         "$1Civic");
      System.out.println(output);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[{brand:"Honda", model:"{year:2022, name:Accord}"}]
[{brand:"Honda", model:"Civic"}]
```